# CircleCI maven build fails, missing pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, circleci

I'm just beginning to experiment with CircleCI and my project stored on Github. I've just followed the standard, vanilla setup, and created a single project with just one workflow.
My github repo structure contains 4 sub-projects (each in their own folder), all on the same hierarchical (root) level:

-- alpha

-- beta

-- setup

-- utilities

I've adapted the config.yml file as follows:

```
version: 2.1
app_src_directory: alpha
orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@0.0.12

workflows:
  maven_test:
    jobs:
      - maven/test # checkout, build, test, and upload test results
```

The build successfuly goes through the Spin up environment, Preparing environment variables, Checkout code, Generate Cache Checksum and Restoring cache stages, but fails on Install Dependencies with the error message:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
mvn dependency:go-offline --settings 'pom.xml'
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] The specified user settings file does not exist: /home/circleci/project/pom.xml

Exited with code exit status 1
CircleCI received exit code 1
```

I have a feeling this is something obvious that I'm too green to figure out. I haven't explicitly mentioned the circleci user anywhere (including my code), so I'm not sure where this reference comes from. The build runs fine locally on my machine, using Maven.

Thanks for any hints !

Comment: It looks like you don't have a pom file in expected location... Does your multi module build has a parent? Can you give a link to the github repository?

Comment: @khmarbaise I thought that the tag/directive/argument "app_src_directory" would point CircleCI/Maven to the right location. There is no overarching multi-project pom at the root level. I merely decided to locate all projects in the same git repository. The repo is private, so can't share unfortunately.
Would "working_directory" be any different/better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
orbs:
  maven: circleci/maven@1.1.0
version: 2.1
workflows:
  maven_test:
    jobs:
      - maven/test:
          app_src_directory: alpha
```

I now get an expected error, which is related to the generated war file not being able to be deployed to a (missing) Tomcat installation - which I will have to address somehow in the CircleCI build image.